# How to add(include) elementor created page in theme file 404.php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I created a page using **elementor**(named as: '**Error-page**'), currently using *linoor* theme. What I want is to load this '**Error-page**' via theme's default **404.php** file (**NOT** using any **plugin**). Should I just type in '**include Error-page.php**' in 404.php file to make it work?

Meta: My goal is to show my custom error page which I created using elementor(named as: Error-page) when invalid url is typed. **One** way of doing it is using plugin(I prefer not to do this for the time being), **2nd** way could be somehow including this custom page in theme's default 404.php file

Note: Im new to wordpress

Answer (score -1):

after thinking about your question, i have 2 solutions for you:

**1. if you do not have code knowledge**

*This way is simple and safer, but have limits than other way - it's not using your template but redirect viewer to your template page. Any way, the same result*

- Build the 404 template with Elementor and publish it
- Open your theme's 404.php file
- In the very first top of the template file **(below <?php tag) paste this code:

  ```
  wp_redirect( '/your-template-slug' );
  exit;
  ```
- Save it and you're done

**2. If you have basic code knowledge:**

*This way is a litle complex, but it alow you to using not for 404 file - but other templates (archive, categories...)*

- Install **"Anywhere Elementor"** plugin
- Build the 404 template as you do with Elementor
- Get your template php shortcode
- Edit the theme's 404.php file to echo out your template
- In case you need more detail guide, i have record a [step by step guide video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esJV-L7qgso) here

Comment: I moved ahead of this scenario, but thank you anyways for answering